# recursive binary search for assembler motorola 68K

Tags: assembly, motorola

I want to code this recursive binary search in assembler motrolla 68K.

```
int binSearch(int key, int &lo, int &hi) {
if(hi < lo)
   return NOT_FOUND;  //RETURN with V = 1  
int mid = (lo+hi) / 2;
if(key == array[mid])
   return mid;
else if(key < array[mid]) // go left
   return binSearch(key, lo, mid-1); // left
else
   return binSearch(key, mid+1, hi); // right
}
```

so I am just wondering if I am coding the `int binsearch(int key,int&lo,int &hi)` part right

any helP!!????????????

```
link       A6,#0
movem.l    D1,D2-(sp)
move.w     8(A6),D1 *key
```

and if I wanted to do `int&low,int hi` would I do the same thing just with A5,A4..ect.?

Answer (score 0):

I found these points you might consider reviewing in your code:

- You need to pass `array` to `binsearch`
- This will only work if `array` is **previously sorted**
- The type of `array` contents should be `int`, to make a valid comparison with `key`

ps: please, could you clarify on the second part? Are you trying to convert C to Assembly?